# Can I ask interview programming questions at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation

I recently have asked couple of programming questions on Stack Overflow which were asked to me during an interview process. I embedded my solution code in the question and asked for a better/optimized solution. But I didn't seem to get a good response. Instead I got a few down votes and was stopped from asking further questions for 3 days.

Here are there links

[Write a program to check given input string have balance brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446061/given-a-string-of-parentheses-write-a-program-to-find-whether-its-valid-or-not)

[Given m bricks of x inches and n bricks of y inches, create row of z inches using combination of the given bricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517469/given-m-bricks-of-x-inches-and-n-bricks-of-y-inches-create-row-of-z-inches-usin)

If someone can specify and point out where I'm going wrong and what type of questions are allowed on Stack Overflow? Is there a problem with how I framed the questions?

Comment: Why didn't you ask this on the Stack Overflow meta?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I saw queries regarding stack overflow here as well, so I asked it here. New to stack exchange/overflow. Should I ask it there now?

Comment: Related (on Meta ProgSE): [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6360/25936)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is largely a problem with how you framed or asked the questions. Programming interview questions are not off topic, much the same as homework oriented questions aren't. But you have to ask carefully otherwise they won't be well received.

Your [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30446061/109702) is not a good question. You state:

> "I want to confirm first of all, if this program is correct as well as if a better/optimized or alternate solution is there to solve this."

Stack Overflow is not a code review site, and asking for recommendations in this way is too vague. Ideally you should post specific problems so that people can give you specific answers. That's not to say you can't ask (because not every question can be super exact), but your question will be regarded as low quality.

Your [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30517469/109702) is a little better:

> "I'm looking for an optimized solution to this which reduces complexity. Can it be done with a single loop?"

The statement *"I'm looking for an optimized solution to this which reduces complexity"* is bad because it is vague and likely to solicit opinion - there could be a hundred more optimised ways of doing it, but which one is best? The statement *"Can it be done with a single loop?"* is **good** because it illustrates the specific problem you have with the current code and asks an exact question.

You could edit those questions to be more specific and concise, but there is no guarantee that someone won't still down vote them. Keep the problem interesting and people are far more likely to engage and try and answer it.